# Applying color on td with different colors in if condition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am applying different text colors on td but when i apply a color on last td it changes the color of all above td's. e.g In the below code the last one is red, after executing this line it changes the color of above td's to red also. how should i overcome with this issue.
//html

```
'<table class="ui-widget" width="100%" border="0"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">'+
        '<thead class="ui-widget-header" id="orderListHead">'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<th><strong> Order# </strong></th>'+
                '<th><strong> Exchange </strong></th>'+    
            '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody id="orderListBody">'+               
        '</tbody>'+
     '</table>'+

 if(orderList== "Buy"){                      
    $("#orderListBody",this.orderListTable)
         .append('<tr><td>'+orderList.ORDER_NUMBER+'</td><td>'+orderList.SHORT_NAME+'</td></tr>')
         .css("color","green");
 }
 if(orderList == "Sell"){                   
    $("#orderListBody",this.orderListTable)
         .append('<tr><td>'+orderList.ORDER_NUMBER+'</td><td>'+orderList.SHORT_NAME+'</td></tr>')
         .css("color","red");
 }
```

Comment: your are aplying css to whole table,add your html code with respect to above script

Comment: you are adding the css to `#orderListBody` not to any specific `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying the CSS to the table, not to the particular row and you really ought not have such duplicate code.

Change your code to this:

```
var newColor;
if (orderList == "Buy") {
    newColor = "green";
} else {
    newColor = "red";
}

$('<tr><td>'+orderList.ORDER_NUMBER+'</td><td>'+orderList.SHORT_NAME+'</td></tr>').css("color", newColor).appendTo($("#orderListBody",this.orderListTable));
```

Not only does this remove the repeated code, but it applies the CSS only to the new row, not to the table selector.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try something like this instead:

```
$("#orderListBody",this.orderListTable).append('<tr class="' + orderList + '"><td>'+orderList.ORDER_NUMBER+'</td><td>'+orderList.SHORT_NAME+'</td></tr>');
```

and in your css add:

```
.Buy {
  color: green;
}
.Sell {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: +1 Much better idea to use a class than set the colour directly.

Answer (score 0):

/*

I am not much clear with your question ..
I think the code below will solve your problem..

*/

```
if(orderList== "Buy"){                       
                    $("#orderListBody",this.orderListTable).append('<tr><td>'+orderList.ORDER_NUMBER+'</td><td  style="color:green">'+orderList.SHORT_NAME+'</td></tr>');
                }
                if(orderList == "Sell"){                    
                    $("#orderListBody",this.orderListTable).append('<tr><td>'+orderList.ORDER_NUMBER+'</td><td style="color:red">'+orderList.SHORT_NAME+'</td></tr>');
            }
```

Comment: Style property should have ";" at the end. So, It should be `style="color:green;"` & `style="color:red;"`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code with a bit more flexability:

```
$("$orderListBody, this.orderListTable)
      .append("<tr class='" orderList + "'><td class='" + orderList + "'>"
             +orderList.ORDER_NUMBER+ "</td><td class='" + orderList + "'>"
             +orderList.SHORT_ORDER + "</td></tr>");
```

Then in your CSS you can do what ever you like for example:

```
tr.Buy { background-color: yellow; }
tr.Sell { background-color: red; }

td.Buy { 
    color: green;
} 

td.Sell {
    color: red;
}
```